# SSL policy errors have been encountered. Error code '0x2'

Tags: ssl-certificate, sharepoint-2013

I am facing certificate validation error after recreated my self  signed  certificate. Initially it was working fine but yesterday I changed it  new certificate since old cert got expired. After this I am getting below error:

An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:

Subject Name: CN=xx.yy.msh.local
Issuer Name: CN=xx.yy.msh.local
Thumbprint: A9E62A621QEHF0A32CF509BC90EACE9827AA1C7A

Errors:

SSL policy errors have been encountered. Error code '0x2'

Site  is running in sharepoint and is trying to call service which is using this certificate. I am running out of ideas and same error  is logged in ULS also. Any help will be really appreciated.

Regards
Sri